# Bigcommerce custom images from Stencil

Tags: bigcommerce

Firstly, wow, Bigcommerce's own forums are dead as heck, huh?

Anyway, I've been working on my theme locally within stencil and for the most part it's been going fine. I did add a grip of images to the /assets/img directory that are displayed by category.js under certain conditions, which worked great when I'm serving from localhost but when I push the theme to Bigcommerce from the commandline (using 'stencil push') these images (and a couple custom icons, etc) are broken. I read the docs that warned me to make sure any added directories have the proper permissions but 1) this is an existing directory and 2) i'm getting a 404 anyway so it's not like they can't be accessed, they're just not there at all. Clearly Push isn't bundling them up, which means I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you using the `{{cdn}}` helper? https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/ZG9jOjIyMDcxOA-handlebars-helpers-reference#example-1

Comment: I'm not, which looks like it's gonna be a problem! Essentially I wanted to make a brand landing page that, prior to the user filtering by brand where it displays a generic message ("There are no products listed under this category.") instead displayed a few images. I did this by generating markup right in the .js and adding it the the dom. I was hoping to get the project, which is 99% css, into production without actually having to learn how webcomponents works but it looks like I'm going to have to? :D